# Telerik Silverlight: RowEditEnded does not fire when edit inline on Grid that only has one row

Tags: telerik-grid

RowEditEnded does not fire when edit inline on Grid that only has one row.

If Grid has more than one row, when I edit inline a row, I can click on another row and this event will fire. In this event, I will implement saving function.
But if Grid has only one row, I click to the empty space below but Grid still know I select the old row and this event does not fire.
(Hit Enter always affect, but some users don't know this way)
How to fix this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, would you like to provide some code so people can see what the problem is and what you already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telerik reply : user should press the Enter key or the Tab key to the end of the editable cells on the same row. 
http://www.telerik.com/forums/roweditended-does-not-fire-when-edit-inline-on-grid-that-only-has-one-row#9XFK1ifa1kSvUUjH-rWa6w